# Looking for a way to load modal content when opening vs. on page load

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have been researching for hours and have not found a solution to my problem.  I have a Wordpress site where I have built a dashboard of metrics.  I have setup modal windows using bootstrap to display details for each metric.  The modal window loads a google sheet using an inline viewer plugin/shortcode.  The issue is that all modal windows are loading in the background on page load causing the page to take up to 60 seconds to load.  I am looking for a solution that will only load the content of the modal windows when you click the metric.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<a class="dash-submetric-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AMI">1</a>

<div id="AMI" class="modal fade" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 80%;">
<div class="modal-content">
<h4 id="AMILabel" class="modal-title">Ashland Move-In Inspections</h4>
<div class="modal-body">
<a class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
<div style="margin-top: -10px;">[this is where my shortcode goes]</div>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default inverted" style="float:right; margin-top: -18px;" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented that by changing [shortcodes] to <shortcodes></shortcodes> so they are not parsed by PHP and then attaching click events as suggested, converting and processing them with Ajax talking in general.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding this components on click with javascript but problem is that shortcodes are generated through PHP which means you would need an Ajax call each time you click on an item.

Found that somebody wanted to tackle the same issue you are facing here so it might be of use for you as well:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140086/execute-a-shortcode-when-clicking-on-a-image